# Position to bottom of flex item

Tags: css

Is there any way to align element (div in our case) to bottom of flex?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/djeQv/1/

```
#images div {
position:relative;
bottom: 0px;
margin-top: -10px;
padding-top: 10px;
cursor: default;
}
```

This usual way didn't worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not position the text absolute? Something like this:

```
#images div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Since this takes the text out of the flow of the document, you will need to add some padding to the bottom of your link to prevent the text from overlapping the image.

I updated your fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/djeQv/2/

Comment: I don't get it in this fiddle it works and on the real page it doesn't? (I actually tested the position absolute but it didn't worked). If you have a sec look at: https://student.sps-prosek.cz/~eisead11it/web/Adv%20E-Shop/Admin/order?order=1 (nick:admin,pass:mnbvcx11)

Comment: works fine for me when i edit the site in chrome inspector. Did you perhaps froget to add the `position:relative` to `#images>a`, as well as the `padding-bottom:25px`

Comment: I did, have a better look. Line 23 in the css. And the position relative (line 20) was already there, but not present on the actual website...

Comment: I see I missed the padding... that explains all